# What is os.log for?

Tags: ios, swift, logging, oslog

I am going through a few Swift tutorials on how to build simple apps, as I am just starting to code. I want to make my app iOS 9 compatible, as I have an iPad 3.  However, all the `os.log` statements generate an error in Xcode which tells me to add an `if #avaliable` statement before any of the `os.log` statements.  What does os.log do, and if I need it, is there an issue using an `if #avaliable` statement for iOS 9 compatibility?  If not, what is the equivalent code for iOS 9 to go in the `else` statement after the `if #avaliable` statement?  Thanks.

Comment: Have you read [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/os/logging)?

Comment: @rmaddy, Yes, I have read the documentation, and I see that it's for logging, but what does it log?  Basic errors, app behavior, so on and so forth?  And what is the iOS 9 equivalent?

Comment: It logs what you tell it to :) – There is still `NSLog()` which isn't as flexible but available on all OS versions.

Comment: @MartinR So is it basically for debugging app crashes and things like that?

Comment: looking at the Apple website tutorial, it uses log to persist data, humph  https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/PersistData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH14-SW1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/os/logging):

> Unified logging is available in iOS 10.0 and later, macOS 10.12 and
>   later, tvOS 10.0 and later, and watchOS 3.0 and later, and supersedes
>   ASL (Apple System Logger) and the Syslog APIs.  Historically, log
>   messages were written to specific locations on disk, such as
>   /etc/system.log.  The unified logging system stores messages in memory
>   and in a data store, rather than writing to text-based log files.

There is no iOS9 equivalent.  You could use a third party logging tool like [CocoaLumberjack](https://github.com/CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack), which is very popular.

As a concrete example of how to use this logging:

```
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
    let bundleID:String = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier ?? "unknown"
    let oslog = OSLog(subsystem: bundleID, category: "Model")
    os_log("%@", log: oslog, type: .info, message)
}
```

Comment: So is it basically for debugging app crashes and things like that?

Comment: @TonyStark4ever it's an advanced NSLog / Print where you can filter and categorise the data.